# How to get a certain element of an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

If I have a RDD[(K, V)] and a key, how do I get the element of the RDD with that key?

I can filter the RDD by key, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: just a side note: use `rdd.lookup(...)` with care. If you find yourself looping over elements and using lookup repetitively, consider another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the PairRDD, we can use `lookup(key)` API. This returns all values associated with the provided key.